# how to avoid for muliple coupons applied on a same product at a time

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to apply only one coupon at a time in a cart page either automatic apply else manually coupon code.
In that we apply only one and I also added stop furture using button yes.
But dynamic coupon apply and automatic coupon both are applied.
so how to do only one applicable coupon in cart page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules and click on the row that contains the coupon code in question. In the "Actions" tab is a setting called `Stop Further Rules Processing`. Set that to Yes and then flush your cache. This option prevents other discounts from being applied.

Comment: That I Did, But dynamic coupon is applied multiple times.

Comment: Maybe a core bug or undue interference from some custom code. What 3rd party extensions do you have installed and did you write any significant amount of custom code?

Comment: Yes, I have used amasty extension for custom coupon code.

Comment: Disable that module temporarily, flush the cache, and then see if my answer works for you. If it does, then you know that issue lives within the 3rd party module. At that point you should inform the developer of the bug and I wouldn't be surprised if they fix it for you.

Comment: Ya, without using the 3rd party extension it works, but with using 3rd party extension applied multiple coupons.

Comment: Ok, that means this is not really an issue for Stack Exchange. You should contact the developer about the bug and ask them to fix it.